# Postfix auth with username containing an at sign?

Tags: authentication, postfix

How can I configure Postfix so that a user sending an email can authenticate with a full email address containing an at sign (@) and a TLD, such as "info@mydomain.com"?

Currently my "info" account is a normal Unix account with a mailbox that's accessed via IMAP. I'm trying to send emails from QuickBooks through my Postfix server, and authenticate with the "info" account, but QuickBooks only lets me enter a full email address with the at sign, and then attempts to login to my server with that full email address. There seems to be no way to make QuickBooks login with just "info", and of course Unix accounts can't contain an at sign.

Is there a way I can tell Postfix to translate "info@mydomain.com" to just "info" *before* authenticating the login?

I tried virtual_alias_maps but it didn't work. I assume because that's maybe more about mail delivery than login authentication.

Comment: What is the authentication backend you use with postfix?

Comment: @clement: I have smtpd_sasl_type set to 'dovecot'.